# How to get file path from user to then pass into functions (argparse)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, argparse

I am writing a program that performs different functions on the contents of a file. At the moment the file is stored in a variable and passed to each of the functions as such:

```
file = "path/to/file"
```

What I want to do is allow the user to enter the path using the command line function I have setup and have it passed to my functions.

However I am unsure on how to implement this into the command line file I have here

**cli.py**

```py
import os, argparse
from . import parse


def validate_file(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("{0} does not exist".format(filename))
    return filename


def dump(filename):
    for record in parse.uniprot_records(filename):
        print(record)

...
(more function definitions)
...

def cli():
    # Create a new parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="UniProt Analysis")

    # Input file
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", dest="filename", type=validate_file, required=True, help="enter input file", metavar="FILE")

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="Enter one of the arguments to run function")

    # Add subparsers
    subparsers.add_parser("dump", help="prints all records").set_defaults(func=dump)

    # Parse the command line
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(type(args.filename))

    # Take the func argument, which points to our function and call it
    args.func(args)
```

So I want to be able to pass the file and also have the function I want to perform on it in the command line e.g.
`pipenv run python program.py path/to/file dump`

Edit: Have added an argument to the parser to get the user's input file. This file is then passed into the `dump`function, which passes the file into this function:

**parse.py**

```py
import gzip
from Bio import SeqIO


def uniprot_records(f):
    records = []

    handle = gzip.open(f)
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "uniprot-xml"):
        records.append(record)
    return records
```

My main function is in a separate module where it simply calls the `cli` function. When I try to run this by doing `pipenv run python uniplot.py -i path/to/file dump` it gives me the following error:

File "/Users/john/workspace/practical-2/uniplot/parse.py", line 24, in uniprot_records
    handle = gzip.open(file_location)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 57, in open
raise TypeError("filename must be a str or bytes object, or a file")

TypeError: filename must be a str or bytes object, or a file

`dump` should simply print out the entire contents of the given file after it has been unzipped using gzip.

Comment: Right now it doesn't look like you're passing the filename as a function argument -  `dump` has no arguments for example - but rather relying on it being in the global namespace. I would follow the answer by @sanjusci but also make your functions take the filename as an argument.

Comment: Yeah that makes some sense. I'll try implement that.

Comment: Okay so I have made some progress. But what is still confusing me is how do I pass filename as an argument to the other functions in the subparsers?

Comment: What do you mean? `args.func(args)` is actually passing all the `args` to the function being called (e.g. `dump`). Given your code as above, I'd expect an error to be thrown for trying to pass arguments to `dump` when it takes none. One example assuming that all your funcs take the same argument (a single filename) would be to do `args.func(args.filename)` where `dump` is defined `def dump(filename):` and then you use `filename` inside dump where you currently use `file`

Comment: Okay that seems to work with regards to passing the file to the function. However now I am being given a TypeError: filename must be a str or bytes object, or a file... The method that handles the file is using gzip to unzip the file, I thought that passing the file through command line would be a str...

Comment: What's giving you that error? How are you passing `filename`?

Comment: `filename` is passed into a function that then parses its contents and returns the names of different proteins in a list using `handle = gzip.open(file_location)` in a different module (**parse.py**). This function works as it should, however `filename` seems to be being passed as a different type. I thought it would be a string as I used @sanjusci's `validate_file` function which returns the path if it is valid.

Comment: It should be a string based off my test of that code, but you can check that by simply adding `print(type(args.filename))` before you call `args.func(args.filename)`. If you still have an issue I'd suggest either editing you question or opening a new one with the new problem. Right now you haven't shown you up-to-date code at all

Comment: Have updated original code. I did the test too and it says it is a string... Confusing

Comment: Look at your code again, you’re calling `args.func(args)` instead of what you need to call: `args.func(args.filename)`

Comment: Oops. Yeah now it works. However I can't use `validate_file(filename)` in the type attribute for the file argument because it requires an argument. There isn't anything I can pass it at this point.. Thank you by the way!

Comment: No, look at the answer you took it from, that line should just be `type=validate_file` you don’t pass it an argument like `whatgoeshere?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please use below syntax.**

```
import argparse, os
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def validate_file(f):
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        # Argparse uses the ArgumentTypeError to give a rejection message like:
        # error: argument input: x does not exist
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("{0} does not exist".format(f))
    return f


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = ArgumentParser(description="Read file form Command line.")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", dest="filename", required=True, type=validate_file,
                        help="input file", metavar="FILE")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add arguments to the `parser` using `parser.add_argument`. These will be passed as a [Namespace](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object to the called function:

```py
import argparse

def dump(args):
    print(args.path)


def cli():
    # Create a new parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    parser.add_argument("path")

    # Add subparsers
    subparsers.add_parser("dump").set_defaults(func=dump)

    # Parse the command line
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Take the func argument, which points to the function and call it
    args.func(args)

cli()
```

The command would look like:

```
python cli.py dump some/file
```

As for the recommended way of doing this, that will depend on your use-case. Passing all arguments to the script through the command-line will allow you to run the script more easily in some automated fashion than through interactive inputs. It will also allow you to rerun the same task more easily in a terminal. If that's not relevant for you than this is mostly a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

For any file which needs inputs from user, I usually create a parser function.
I would do it in a following way:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import sys

def my_parser():
    """
    Creates argument parser.
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Input File
    parser.add_argument('path',
                        type=str,
                        help='some help text')

    # function name
    parser.add_argument('function',
                        type=str,
                        help='some help text')

    return parser


def main(args=None):
    """
    display user input
    """

    # Create parser
    subparser = my_parser()

    # Parse command-line input
    args = subparser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    print('User path is -> {}'.format(args.path))
    print('User function is -> {}'.format(args.function))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

1) You can take path from user
2) Function name he wants to execute

From Command line you can run it as:

```
python pathtoyourpythonscript filepath functionname
```

Then inside the main function, you can write a if else loop depending on the user input.
I hope this helps.